# Fortran procedure pointers as argument. Error: Invalid procedure argument at (1)

Tags: pointers, fortran, procedure

I'm trying to give a function as argument to another function, by using a pointer. I keep getting the error: `Error: Invalid procedure argument at (1)`. Concerning the argument f_ptr in diff in the main program. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
module functions
contains

function f(x) result(y)
    double precision x, y
    y = sin(x)
end function f

end module

MODULE numerical_math
contains
function diff(f, x, degree) result(df)
    double precision, intent(in) :: x
    double precision :: h, df
    integer :: degree, i, j
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: lst
    pointer :: f
    interface
        function f(x) result(y)
            double precision :: x, y
        end function f
    end interface

    ...

end function diff
END MODULE numerical_math

program main
    use numerical_math
    use functions
    implicit none
    integer :: first
    procedure (f), pointer :: f_ptr => null ()
    f_ptr => f
    print *, f_ptr(1.d0)

    do first = 1,9
        print *, diff(f_ptr, 0.d0, first)
    end do    
end program main
```

Comment: You do not need function pointers at all when passing around functions. Function pointers were only added in Fortran 2003 for more advanced stuff like storing the function address and changing it for some other later. You just need normal function arguments.

Comment: @SamWoef which compiler and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using mingw32-gcc-fortran on netbeans IDE

Comment: what happens if you call `diff(f, 0.d0, first)` in `main` and in `diff` remove the `pointer` line?

Comment: Still the same error. To be clear, I leave the interface, right?

Comment: @jack if I just remove the pointer line, doesn't the function f has to be declared in diff somehow?

Comment: @SamWoef `f` is defined in the `functions` module which you `use` in your `main` program`.

Comment: actually, i cannot even reproduce your error using ifort nor gfortran under linux. you might wanna try it out using a different platform/compiler

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `diff` function should only receive a function as argument and you don't need to change that function (i.e. you don't want to change the target function).
Then you only need to delete the `pointer :: f` line in your `diff` function:

```
function diff(f, x, degree) result(df)
    double precision, intent(in) :: x
    double precision :: h, df
    integer :: degree, i, j
    integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: lst
    ! pointer :: f  REMOVE THIS LINE
    interface
        function f(x) result(y)
            double precision :: x, y
        end function f
    end interface

    ...

end function diff
```

Comment: (not the OP): as in, the type declaration is implicit because of the interface statement?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou There is no _type_ declaration as for data objects but rather _interface_ declarations. If you need the _pointer_ attribute then you might work with something as `procedure(f_interface), pointer :: f` where you defined an `abstract interface f_interface` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter the same problem, I solved the problem by making the project in Fortran 95. In Fortran 95 it compiles when you use Jack's suggestion (removing the `pointer :: f` line and giving the function as argument instead of the pointer). I haven't found a solution for the problem in Fortran 90.